# Google Maps Places API is no longer returning county (adminstrative_area_level_2)

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I've been using the Google Places v 3.0 API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) and until today, it always returned the county (i.e. type: administrative_area_level_2) in the address_components field.  Everything else is still there, but county is missing.  Did something change?  Is this affecting anyone else?

Comment: I'm able to get around this by calling the Geocoder() library to get the county, but it doesn't make sense that they quit returning county (administrative_area_level_2).

Comment: fixed:  https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=7139

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem (at 10 September 2014), but according to Google support it should now (16 September 2014) be fixed.

Comment: yes, I reported that bug on Google support and I confirmed that my old code is working again and I no longer need the workaround.

Comment: It seems this case is happening again. Not sure when it changed, but certain zipcodes will still not return a County.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem and visited this page multiple times, but it wasn't until today that I figured out what was going on.

Depending on the location that you give, multiple counties in the US may hold space there. In my case, I would provide zip codes (for example, 79556) that would not always return a county.

The reason is that some zip codes (like 79556) actually cross several counties. [(see this map)](http://www.zipmap.net/Texas/Nolan_County.htm)

Make sure that the search that you're making does not step into the space of multiple counties. If it does, you will not get an array of all of the counties that the provided location is within; you will instead get no county value at all.

Comment: you are correct regarding the zip codes that cross multiple counties, and I too was wondering why the API did not return a list of counties instead of single counties.
Have you found any other services that enable this functionality?  I am looking into several options and thought I would start here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't. We ended up using a large MySQL table to connect zip codes to county areas. I can't help but think there's got to be a better way, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Reading in 2022 and it still doesn't return a list of counties, did you find any better way?

Comment: @Cyberdelphos I haven't used the API since then, so unfortunately, no.

Comment: I ended up using the localities and searching each one to find what counties are there.